# Break shape points into separate objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a path, for example, looking like this: 
[image: Path]

I want to break it into separate points, no need to keep bezier curves data, just simple points. Is there a way to do it in Illustrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the object. Navigate the menu bar: `Select > Object > Directional Handles`. Press Delete. Now all you have is points!